# Way to simplify this array insertion code?

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean, refactoring

If I have this code:

```
array[0] = a < b ? c : d
array[1] = a < b ? d : c
```

Is there a way to simplify it elegantly?

I know I can do something like this to avoid the double boolean check:

```
if (a < b)
{
    array[0] = c;
    array[1] = d;
}
else
{
    array[0] = d;
    array[1] = c;
}
```

But it's rather verbose.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Thats not really insertion, more of a really weird sort. Are `a` and `c` actually related?

Comment: Yes, a is hashcode-related.

Comment: You could refactor `a < b` into a local boolean to avoid performing the comparison twice, but you'd still be performing two `?` operations..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute the index to assign the variable to, instead of which variable to use for each index.

```
int cLocation = a < b ? 0 : 1;
array[cLocation] = c;
array[1 - cLocation] = d;
```